# Events loading too slow

Tags: solidity, blockchain, javascript, events

I have a dapp running on rinkeby at the moment, you can try it now on [cryptogol.io](https://www.cryptogol.io/), but I am facing a problem when reading events from the Blockchain. For example, yesterday I make the events `happens`, so everyone can interact with the site. Here is the code for listening to the event (it is being ran every time someone opens the page at [www.cryptogol.io/market.html](http://www.cryptogol.io/market.html):

```
listenForEvents: function() {
  console.log("escuchando")
    App.contracts.KickerADN.deployed().then(function(instance) {
        instance.AdnCreated({}, {
            fromBlock: 0,
            toBlock: 'latest'
        }).watch(function(error, event) {
            App.loadBody(event.args._adn.toNumber());
        });
    });
}
```

When you open the page it can take more than 1 minute to load the event. The function is being called normally but the event is not getting it on time.
Any idea?

Comment: You are retrieving all events from block 0, this is a demanding task. You can try to load on demand, start from the latest and go backward. And keep a cache of previously loaded events, so you do not have to reload everything from the blockchain.

Answer (score 1):

The event of the tnx call only fired when the tnx was confirmed a.k.a when tnx was including in a sealed block so it takes time.

Comment: Thank you... But the tnx was confirmed yesterday, I know it can takes time, but more than a minute to load something that already was confirmed is not very good, is it?

Comment: No, each time you call the function it will create a new tnx; not the old one

Comment: that's for funstions that writes on the blockchain, but I am just trying to read from the blockchain...

Comment: Then you can get tnx's receipts/logs to extract the events from it

Answer (score 0):

How about change design? It is loading all blocks. 
AdnCreated is event accessor and the 1st arg is search condition for indexed event. It will reduce scanning target count. 2nd arg is skipper. `fromBlock` allows you to skip some block. And so if you design your contract to ignorable obsoleted state, checkpointing would make your log feching faster. And putting cache server is also one choice. Some of users would say it's centralized entity though, actually that server isn't killing fund safety.